# Creating a shallow copy of a concurrent collection in Java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I want to create a shallow copy of a concurrent collection, turning it into a regular collection. Is there a problem with doing it like this:

```
ledger = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>(); // this line is somewhere else in the program
//...
ArrayDeque<Operation> ledger_copy;
ledger_copy = new ArrayDeque<>(ledger);
```

The reason I ask is because while `ledger` is being used in the constructor of `ArrayDeque` it might be concurrently written to in other parts of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you consider "a problem". However, the usage of these collection classes is correct in the sense they are meant to be used.

More specifically, the iterators exposed by [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) are weakly consistent:

> Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the
> state of the deque at some point at or since the creation of the
> iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may
> proceed concurrently with other operations.

Because of this, the elements in the `ArrayDeque` will also reflect the state of the `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` at some prior point in time.

Comment: I am aware that it is weakly consistent and that is not a problem for me, I want to return the state at some point in time, not necessarily the latest. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a problem with doing it like this

The problem is that `new ArrayDeque<>(ledger)` doesn't necessarily give you a snapshot of the *current* state of `ledger`.  Elements that are added to or removed from `ledger` while the `ArrayDeque` is being initialized (from `ledger`) *may or may not* be included in `ledger_copy`.

This follows from the javadocs for `ArrayDeque` and `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.  The former says that `ledger`'s iterator will be used by the `ArrayDeque(Collection)` constructor to fetch the elements.  The latter states that the iterator is *weakly consistent*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ConcurrentLinkedDeque's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) states that iteration is supported, and its behaviour in the face of concurrent modification:

> Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the queue at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations. Elements contained in the queue since the creation of the iterator will be returned exactly once.
>
> ...
>
> Bulk operations that add, remove, or examine multiple elements, such as addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>), removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate<? super E>) or forEach(java.util.function.Consumer<? super E>), are not guaranteed to be performed atomically. For example, a forEach traversal concurrent with an addAll operation might observe only some of the added elements.